# discord js | send message to online members

Tags: discord.js

Hello trying to make so when a command is executed it sends a pm to online members but I cant really get it to work as I want.

```
Client.on('message', (message) => {
if(message.content === config.prefix + "play") {
    let onlineMembers = message.guild.members.filter(member => member.presence.status === "online") //only green status
    console.log(onlineMembers)
    for (let i = 0; i < onlineMembers; i++) {
        onlineMembers[i]
    }
}
```

That dosent work anyone know how to make it ?

Comment: You just forgot to add `.send()` and you can use forEach which is easier to understand `onlineMembers.forEach(member=> { member.send("Hello") }) `

Comment: Thanks @Cursed, forEach worked out great!